# CMake trying to link directory as an executable if their names match

Tags: cmake

I'm encountering an annoying error in CMake where the following conditions hold:

1. A target name is identical to name of the directory defining the target.
2. I am using the `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` property for the target.

Under these conditions, I get the errors:

- `Linking CXX executable .`
- `/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file .:   Is a directory`

CMake seems to be trying to build a target named `.` , apparently trying to refer to the current directory name rather than the desired target name.

---

Here's a trivial example. My file tree is:

```
/tmp/example$ tree
.
├── build
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── hello_world
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        └── HelloWorld.cpp
```

src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
set (ARBITRARY_OUTPUT_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
add_subdirectory(hello_world)
```

src/hello_world:

```
add_executable(hello_world HelloWorld.cpp)
set_property(TARGET hello_world PROPERTY RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${ARBITRARY_OUTPUT_DIR})
```

...and `HelloWorld.cpp` itself is a trivial Hello World program, with a `main()` method.

---

I run:

```
/tmp/example/build$ cmake ../src/ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=gcc-4.8 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++-4.8 -G"Unix Makefiles"
/tmp/example/build$ make VERBOSE=1
```

And I get:

```
[ 50%] Building CXX object hello_world/CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/HelloWorld.o
cd /tmp/example/build/hello_world && /usr/bin/g++-4.8     -O3 -DNDEBUG   -o CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/HelloWorld.o -c /tmp/example/src/hello_world/HelloWorld.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable .
cd /tmp/example/build/hello_world && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/g++-4.8   -O3 -DNDEBUG   CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/HelloWorld.o  -o . -rdynamic
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file .: Is a directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As you can see, `CMakeFiles/hello_world.dir/link.txt` sets the linking target as `-o .` , which obviously won't work.

---

**Is this a bug in CMake, or am I doing something wrong? Is there some workaround for this?**

My tools are:

- cmake version 3.5.1
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus)
- g++-4.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your top-level build directory contains *hello_world* directory because of command `add_subdirectory(hello_world)`.

By setting `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` property to top-level build directory, you want to create executable file with name *hello_world* there.

But in single directory it is impossible to have both **file and directory with the same name**.

You need to rename either subdirectory or executable or change directory to place executable.

Comment: ARRRG. I did not think of that. Thank you :D